# Обновление в Google play для unity

Tags: google-play, apk, unity3d-android

Подскажите, при отправке обновления apk на Google Play, выдаётся сообщение "apk-файл с кодом версии 1 уже существует", пробовал менять в Unity в "Player settings" и version code и bundle code, по отдельности и вместе. Все равно это сообщение. Где поменять версию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия Unity: 2017.4.18f1

Comment: скриншот бы с ошибкой

Comment: вы можете найти такое окошко у себя, или вы там уже пробовали менять?

Comment: Да, я там и менял.

Comment: советуют использовать app_bunle вместо апк

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно менять не версию приложения, а версию кода. Гугл не принимает пакеты с одинаковой версией кода. У вас такое приблизительно сообщение должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вам нужно [проверить](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html?_ga=2.165585535.134082114.1578906888-1980634245.1578906888) `build.settings` и установить версию кода больше чем 1, например 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно помочь.[Вот](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning) доки гугла на этот счет.

Answer (score 0):

После обновления Unity до последней версии и NDK до 16 выгрузка APK прошла успешно.